# Obtaining geographic decimal coordinates from proprietary text format using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

Using only Notepad++ with regex support I would like to extract some data from a txt file, representing geographic coordinates and organize the output like that:

- `-123456789` becomes `-123.456789`
- `123456789`  becomes  `123.456789`
- `-23456789`  becomes  `-23.456789`
- `56789`      becomes  `0.056789`
- `-89`        becomes  `-0.000089`

Tried this: `(-?)([0-9]*)([0-9]{6})`  but fails when input is less than 6 digits long

Comment: what you mean by becomes "replace"?

Comment: Maybe multiplying by **"0.000001"** : `bc -l <<<'.000001*-89'`

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to use Notepad++ as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 2 steps in notepad++ to do this. First, let's take a look at the regex:

```
(?<sign>-?)(?<first>\d+(?=\d{6}))?(?<last>\d+)
```

captures the necessary parts in groups.

Explanation: (you can lose the named grouping if you want)

```
(?<sign>-?)                    # read the '-' sign
(?<first>\d+(?=\d{6}))?        # read as many digits as possible,
                               # leaving 6 digits at the end.
(?<last>\d+)                   # read the remaining digits.
```

see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7TmJk6/1)

How to use this in notepad++? Using a two step-search and replace:

```
(-?)(\d+(?=\d{6}))?(\d+)
```

replace with:

```
\1(?2\2.:0.)000000\3           # copy sign, if group 2 contains any
                               # values, copy them, followed by '.'.
                               # If not show a '0.'
                               # Print 6 zero's, followed by group 3.
```

Next, replace the superfluous zeros.

```
\.(0+(?=\d{6}\b))(\d{6})       # Replace the maximum number of zero's
                               # leaving 6 digits at the end.
```

replace with:

```
.\2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with three steps :

- Step1 : replace  : `(-?)\b(\d{1,6})\b`    with  `\10000000\2`
- Step2 : replace  : `(-?)(\d{0,})(\d{6})`  with  `\1\2.\3`
- Step3 : replace  :  `0{2,}\.`             with  `0.`

The idea is simple :

- In the first step comple all the numbers less than 6 length with 6
  zeros before to insure the length should be more than 6
- In the step two put the dot before the 6th number
- Step three replace all the multiple zeros before the dot with just one

In the end the output

```
-123.456789 
123.456789
-23.456789
0.056789
-0.000089
```

Check the three steps :

[image: Step one]

[image: Step two]

[image: Step three]

Comment: Your first step adds seven zeros instead of six as written in your comment ... but  of course still works  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin available for notepad++:

```
editor.rereplace('(\d+)', lambda m: ('%f' % (float(m.group(1))/1000000)))
```